# Chrome - how to find out which runtime args are used?

Tags: google-chrome

For example, if I run "chrome -incognito", how can I verify "incognito" from inside Chrome?

I have checked "chrome://settings", but found nothing useful.

Background:

I run Chrome with the latest version (114) from VS Code.

My VS Code has a launch.json file which sets the runtime args.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [

    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:8100/",
      "runtimeArgs": [
         "--disable-web-security"
       ],
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to verify that the runtimeArgs settings are actually applied to the launched Chrome.

Thank you